# antd checkbox in antd table not clickable

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, antd

I am trying to implement antd table with checkbox in my react application.

but the checkbox is not clickable only the header checkbox is clickable

here is my code .

```
const columns = [
    {
        title: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
    },
    {
        title: 'Age',
        dataIndex: 'age',
    },
    {
        title: 'Address',
        dataIndex: 'address',
    },
];
```

I am just using a dummy data here to populate the table

```
const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 46; i++) {
    data.push({
        key: i,
        name: `Edward King ${i}`,
        age: 32,
        address: `London, Park Lane no. ${i}`,
    });
}

const TestTable = () => {
    const [selectedRowKeys, setSelectedRowKeys] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const start = () => {
        setLoading(true);
        // ajax request after empty completing
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSelectedRowKeys([]);
            setLoading(false);
        }, 1000);
    };
    const onSelectChange = (newSelectedRowKeys) => {
        console.log('selectedRowKeys changed: ', newSelectedRowKeys);
        setSelectedRowKeys(newSelectedRowKeys);
    };
    const rowSelection = {
        selectedRowKeys,
        onChange: onSelectChange,
    };
    const hasSelected = selectedRowKeys.length > 0;
    return (
        <div>
            <div
                style={{
                    marginBottom: 16,
                }}
            >
                <Button type="primary" onClick={start} loading={loading}>
                    Reload
                </Button>
                <span
                    style={{
                        marginLeft: 8,
                    }}
                >
                    {hasSelected ? `Selected ${selectedRowKeys.length} items` : ''}
                </span>
            </div>
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={data} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default TestTable
```

I am using code from antd documentation to test

Comment: What do you mean with " the checkbox is not clickable only the header checkbox is clickable"? I tried your code and it works, clicking the checkbox update the value